# Why scan clustered index instead seek nonclustered index?

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

There is SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
  ( 
     id        INT, 
     firstname VARCHAR(50), 
     surname   VARCHAR(50) 
  ); 

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_users_id 
  ON users (id); 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_users_firstname 
  ON users (firstname); 

SELECT firstname, 
       surname 
FROM   users 
WHERE  firstname = 'John';
```

I do not understand why for the above SELECT request, Engine of SQL Server 2019 selected follows Execution Plan:

[image]

**Why the Clustered Index is scanned?** I thought, faster is:

1. seek Nonclustered Index;
2. move on a Clustered Index by Clustered Index Pointer, which
   storing in Leaf Node of Nonclustered Index;
3. and take rest `surname` value from there.

Comment: More information will be needed.  If it's a small table, it may be faster to do a scan.  Upload the execution plane to pastetheplan.

Comment: I am not expert in database design. Now table is empty. Does Execution Plan depend on it?

Comment: @AdamShakhabov, the cost-based optimizer uses estimated row counts to determine the optimal plan. Insert a couple of rows and update statistics and you'll probably see the expected index seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key idea here is that your index contains `(firstname,id)`, but not `surname`.  So the options for this query

```
SELECT firstname, 
       surname 
FROM   users 
WHERE  firstname = 'John';
```

are

1) Scan the clustered index

2) Seek the non-clustered index, and *then* for every matching row in the index, Seek on the Clustered Index to find the `surname`.  It's this "bookmark lookup" that is the most expensive part of the query, and if a reasonable percentage of your users are named 'John', it may well be cheaper just to scan the clustered index.

This is why we have [indexes with included columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15).  You can add `surname` to the index to enable this query to seek on the non-clustered index, and avoid the bookmark lookup.  The index would then be a "covering index" for the query.  eg

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_users_firstname 
  ON users (firstname) 
   include (surname);
```

Comment: _contains (firstname,id)_? This **nonclustered** index also contains `id`?

Comment: Yep.  `id` is the clustered index key, so it's included in every nonclustered index as the "row locator".  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish among the various Johns.

Comment: _if a reasonable percentage_. However, how it possible estimate this percentage? Which metrics engine use for it?

Comment: SQL Server tracks statistics on the leading column of each index, and will have a histogram tracking the frequency of each distinct value.  So a query for 'John' might get an clustered index scan, while one for 'Archibald' uses a non-clustered index seek + bookmark lookup.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15